# Initialize object for unicode fonts

Tags: python, object, unicode, character-set

I wrote a class object to access mathematical alphanumeric symbols from the unicode block as described on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols

```
# San-serif
LATIN_SANSERIF_NORMAL_UPPER = (120224, 120250)
LATIN_SANSERIF_NORMAL_LOWER = (120250, 120276)
LATIN_SANSERIF_BOLD_UPPER = (120276, 120302)
LATIN_SANSERIF_BOLD_LOWER = (120302, 120328)
LATIN_SANSERIF_ITALIC_UPPER = (120328, 120354)
LATIN_SANSERIF_ITALIC_LOWER = (120354, 120380)
LATIN_SANSERIF_BOLDITALIC_UPPER = (120380, 120406)
LATIN_SANSERIF_BOLDITALIC_LOWER = (120406, 120432)

class MathAlphanumeric:
    def __init__(self, script, font, style, case):
        self.script = script
        self.font = font
        self.style = style
        self.case = case
        
    def charset(self):
        start, end = eval('_'.join([self.script, self.font, self.style, self.case]).upper())
        for c in range(start, end):
            yield chr(c)
    
    @staticmethod
    def supported_scripts():
        return {'latin', 'greek', 'digits'}
    
    @staticmethod
    def supported_fonts():
        return {'serif', 'sanserif', 'calligraphy', 'fraktor', 'monospace', 'doublestruck'}
    
    @staticmethod
    def supported_style():
        return {'normal', 'bold', 'italic', 'bold-italic'}
    
    @staticmethod
    def supported_case():
        return {'upper', 'lower'}
```

And to use it, I'll do:

```
ma = MathAlphanumeric('latin', 'sanserif', 'bold', 'lower')
print(list(ma.charset()))
```

[out]:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

The code works as expected but to cover all the mathematical alphanum symbols, I'll have to to enumerate through all the start and end symbols from the `script * fonts * style * case` no. of constants.

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to create the desired `MathAlphanumeric` object?
- Is there a way to avoid the initialisation of `script * fonts * style * case` no. of constants, in order for `MathAlphanumeric.charset()` to work as expected?
- Has an object or function like this been available in some unicode.org related library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) standard library, scpecifically :

- [`unicodedata.lookup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup) :

  > Look up character by name. If a character with the given name is found, return the corresponding character. If not found, `KeyError` is raised.
- [`unicodedata.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name) :

  > Returns the name assigned to the character chr as a string.

A quick example :

```py
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(0x1d5a0))
'MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL A'
>>> unicodedata.lookup("MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL A")
''
>>> unicodedata.name(chr(0x1d504))
'MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL A'
>>> unicodedata.lookup("MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL A")
''
```

Now you have to find all the names that `unicodedata` expects for your use cases, construct the corresponding string from them, and call `lookup`.

Here is a mini proof-of-concept :

```py
import unicodedata
import string


def charset(script: str, font: str, style: str, case: str):
    features = ["MATHEMATICAL"]
    # TODO: use script
    assert font in MathAlphanumeric.supported_fonts(), f"invalid font {font!r}"
    features.append(font.upper())
    assert style in MathAlphanumeric.supported_style(), f"invalid style {style!r}"
    if style != "normal":
        if font == "fraktur":
            features.insert(-1, style.upper())  # "bold" must be before "fraktur"
        elif font in ("monospace", "double-struck"):
            pass  # it has only one style, and it is implicit
        else:
            features.append(style.upper())
    assert case in MathAlphanumeric.supported_case(), f"invalid case {case!r}"
    features.append("CAPITAL" if case == "upper" else "SMALL")
    return tuple(unicodedata.lookup(" ".join(features + [letter]), ) for letter in string.ascii_uppercase)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("".join(charset("latin", "sans-serif", "bold", "lower")))
    # 
    print("".join(charset("latin", "fraktur", "bold", "upper")))
    # 
    print("".join(charset("latin", "monospace", "bold", "upper")))
    # 
    print("".join(charset("latin", "double-struck", "bold", "upper")))
    # KeyError: "undefined character name 'MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL C'"
```

(and I changed a bit your `supported_fonts` method : `return {'serif', 'sans-serif', 'calligraphy', 'fraktur', 'monospace', 'double-struck'}`)

But there are a lot of caveats in Unicode : it holds all the glyphs you could possibly want, but not organized in a coherent way (due to historical reasons). The failure in my example is caused by :

```py
>>> unicodedata.name("")  # the letter copied from the Wikipedia page
'MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL B'
>>> unicodedata.name("ℭ")  # same, but for C
'BLACK-LETTER CAPITAL C'
```

So you will need a lot of special cases.

Also :

- using `eval` is considered a bad practice (cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)), if you can avoid it you should.
- using the decimal value for unicode "*characters*" is not convenient, I had to convert from and to hexadecimal to compare your code with the Wikipedia page. Just prefixing with `0x` suffices to tell Python it is an hexadecimal value, but apart from looking "strange" it works exactly the same : `0x1d5a0 == 120224` is True.
- using a class with only one method that gets its parameters from the instance `__init__` is considered a [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), you can just make it a function, simpler and cleaner. If what you want is a [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) you could use Python modules instead.
- the supported scripts, fonts, styles and cases are constant, you could make them *class variables* instead of putting them in `staticmethod`s.